# Excel: get the address referenced in one formula, and use it in another formula

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to obtain the address of a referenced cell, in Excel, in a way that it can be used in another formula?

I have a cell that references another, contents of B1 =Address!A4.  In another cell I want to get the cell reference contained in B1 and use it to obtain the value in a cell relative to the referenced cell.  I do not want to search for the value of the cell Address!A4 because the range in which I would be searching may contain multiple matches.  I want a reference to the cell.

Is there a way to do this?

For example:

a row of cells contains values **A1**="123 E 400 S", **B1**="123", **C1**="400"
a cell contains a reference to one of those cells: **G8**=**B1**

So in the cell **G8** the value "123" is displayed.
I want to place in cell **F8** something that will use the reference in **G8** as a "pointer" or index to **B1** that I can then offset to get at **A1**.

I would like to do this **F8**=OFFSET(CELL("contents",**G8**),0,-1) which would cause the value "123 E 400 S" to be displayed.  Sadly, this does not work, I get a #REF! error.

This may seem like a candidate for INDEX, VLOOKUP, MATCH, etc., but I do not want to try to define the range of cells to look in, it may change.  And the potential search string "123" may be duplicated in the range even if I were to define it.

It seems like I should be able to use the reference I already know, go to that cell, and then work with cells relative to that.

Any ideas?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you are after `indirect`.

Comment: OFFSET()? it is hard to answer without more information.  Please include in your original post some test data and expected output, for us visual learners.

Comment: Tony, thanks for adding more information to your question, was my answer not helpful though? It seems to achieve what you are asking...

Answer (score 2):

Edit: **An easier method**

It might be easier to just have the cell address in a cell somewhere, and use `INDIRECT` from *both* cells B1 and C1, then you don't need the extra functions described below!

[image: indirect]

---

**VBA method: User-defined functions**

If you can save your workbook as a macro-enabled `.xlsm` then you could use a User-defined function to get the formula, and extract the cell address. Add this to a module in your workbook's VBA editor (press `Alt`+`F11`, Insert>Module).

```
Function GetFormula(rng As Range) As String
    GetFormula = rng.Formula
End Function
```

Example use, note the formula in C1 is `=GetFormula`, but the value shown is the formula in B1:

[image: get function]

Then you can either use the cell formula `RIGHT`, or do it directly in VBA with another function. The advantage of doing it in VBA is any parsing you do will be clearer, you could go as far as using RegExp.

```vb
Function GetEndRange(rng As Range) As String
    Dim str As String
    str = rng.Formula
    ' Get the characters to the right of an exclamation point
    ' Assumes formula ended in an address, could do more complicated parsing here
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - InStr(str, "!"))
    GetEndRange = str
End Function
```

Use:

[image: end range]

Now you can use a cell formula (or a more complicated macro) to access the offset cell. Here is the cell formula way to do it:

```vb
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Address!" & GetEndRange(B1),TRUE),1,0)
' Evaluated as:
' =OFFSET(INDIRECT("Address!A4",TRUE),1,0)
' =OFFSET(Address!$A$4,1,0)
' =Address!$A$5
```